# OSGI framework hangs when loading native library

Tags: java, windows, dll, service, osgi

Situation: Open source OSGI framework SMILA (http://www.eclipse.org/smila/) started as Windows Service with the aid of Apache commons-daemon (http://commons.apache.org/daemon/).  Trying to load a DLL via `System.loadLibrary()` from OSGI bundle while `Manifest.mf` includes `Bundle-NativeCode: path/to/dll`.

Environment: Windows Server 2003, Java 1.6

Error: During the invocation of `System.loadLibrary()` the complete Java process hangs. When the service is stopped `System.loadLibrary()` finish and code execution goes on until the OSGI framework shut down.

The error doesn’t occur on Windows Server 2008 or if the OSGI framework isn’t started as service.

The DLL itself is stripped down to no functionality for testing. All imports are static and the only depended library is `kernel32.ddl`.

Could anyone imagine why this is happening and how to fix it?

---

Manifest containing DLL:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: NTFS Utils Acl Win32 Library
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.eccenca.utils.ntfs.acl.win32
Bundle-Version: 2.2.0
Bundle-Vendor: brox IT-Solutions GmbH
Fragment-Host: com.eccenca.utils.ntfs
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86))
Bundle-NativeCode: ntfsacl/Release/NtfsAcl.dll
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6+
```

Manifest containing code:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: NTFS Utils Acl
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.eccenca.utils.ntfs
Bundle-Version: 2.2.0
Bundle-Vendor: brox IT-Solutions GmbH
Export-Package: com.eccenca.processing.acl,
 com.eccenca.utils.ntfs
Import-Package: org.apache.commons.io;version="1.4.0",
 org.apache.commons.lang,
 org.apache.commons.logging;version="1.1.1",
 org.eclipse.smila.blackboard;version="0.8.0",
 org.eclipse.smila.datamodel,
 org.eclipse.smila.processing;version="0.8.0",
 org.eclipse.smila.processing.pipelets;version="0.8.0",
 org.eclipse.smila.utils.config;version="0.8.0",
 org.eclipse.smila.utils.service;version="0.8.0",
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.4.0"
SMILA-Pipelets: com.eccenca.processing.acl.AccessListConverterPipelet
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

Code snipped with `System.loadLibrary()` invocation:

```
public class ACLList {
  private static final org.apache.commons.logging.Log LOG = 
      org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(ACLList.class);

  static {
    try {
      LOG.debug("Start loading library");
      System.loadLibrary("NtfsAcl");
      if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
        LOG.info("NTFS ACL library was succesfully loaded");
      }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      LOG.error(e);
    }
  }

  private ACLList() {
  }

  public static native ArrayList<ACLEntry> getAccessFor(String path, 
      String serverName) throws IOException;

}
```

Comment: Could you include some code, and a more complete manifest of your bundle?

Comment: Maybe `jstack` could show something usable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues with the situation you described; I don't know exactly how Equinox handles native code, so I'll just present them to you both.

### Bundle-NativeCode requires at least one parameter

You use a `Bundle-NativeCode` header that just defines a library, and it seems you use `Eclipse-PlatformFilter` to specify what that library is intended for. Section 3.10 of the [spec](http://www.osgi.org/Download/Release4V43) shows that you need at least one parameter for the library to be selected.

You can change your `Bundle-NativeCode` header to read

```
Bundle-NativeCode: ntfsacl/Release/NtfsAcl.dll;osname=win32
```

and your bundle will be able to find the right library.

### Load only from your own bundle

Judging from your code, it could be possible that you define the library in one bundle, and try to load it in another; that doesn't work, a bundle can only load a library that it contains itself.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I added the parameter “osname” to my manifest as proposed. Unfortunately nothing changed. Furthermore I moved the library into one bundle together with the code. Didn’t take effect either.  Since the bundle containing the DLL was a fragment of the bundle containing the code this should work anyway.

Comment: I also tried it without any OSGI and native code specific stuff before by setting the java parameter java.library.path=folder/containing/dll (outside of a bundle) on startup. The framework always hangs when System.loadLibrary() is invoked. The problem has nothing to do with not finding the DLL; framework just hangs while loading. Not until shutdown of OSGI framework execution of code goes on.

Comment: Weird to see that it also hangs when the library is _not_ managed by OSGi. If I were you, I would ask this question on the Equinox mailing list, and see whether this is a known problem on the exact OS you use.