# OSGi service: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError calling DLL -- NO error when DLL called as unit test

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, osgi, swig

A Java class made for video coding loads a DLL including C++ code

```
Unpacking debugging symbols for VideoSource.dll to \path
Checking for VideoSource.pdb...
Checking for videosource.pdb...
```

and then tries to instantiate a native (C++) class from that DLL:

```
    // VideoSource() is implemented in C++ and wrapped with JNI, 
    // wrapper files were generated with SWIG 
    _videoProvider = new generated.VideoSource();
```

That works when the Java class is executed as a JUnit test (video data is extracted).

**Same thing does not work when I launch the Java class as an OSGi service.**

Essentially, the same code is executed. The DLL is still loaded successfully but the instantiation of the native (C++) class shown above now throws an exception:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: generated.VideoSourceSWIGJNI.new_VideoSource()J
```

**What is different when I launch the Java class as an OSGi service instead of executing it as a JUnit test? What can I do to make it work?**

**BACKGROUND**
generated.VideoSource() is

```
    public VideoSource() {
       this(VideoSourceSWIGJNI.new_VideoSource(), true);
    }
```

VideoSourceSWIGJNI.new_VideoSource() is

```
    public final static native long new_VideoSource();
```

C++ implementation is

```
VideoSource::VideoSource() {    
   // init frame count
   m_frame_cnt = 0;
   [..]
}
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't find the dll for some reason. Have your searched for OSGi + native libraries? There is some documentation out there, AFAIK. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Puce, for pushing me a bit. After asking "would I have to try anything at all"? I got the answer relative quickly:

In order to resume sources ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533595/osgi-framework-hangs-when-loading-native-library), [2](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Manifest), [3](http://josh-in-antarctica.blogspot.de/2008/05/visualizer-part-2-osgi-native-libraries.html), [4](http://holistictendencies.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/bundle-nativecode-using-platform-specific-dlls-from-osgi/)) with my own words:

**When native code, e.g. .so or .dll libraries, shall be used in an OSGi bundle, corresponding libraries have to be declared in the bundle's manifest.**

The manifest file may either be edited explicitely, as stated in mentioned sources, or implicitely via an appropriate plugin, e.g. apache felix, when using maven. Used plugin is configured in the POM file and will modify the manifest automatically.